# RMI security and design

Tags: java, rmi

I have a server which allows RMI connections. It exposes a "Server" object on the registry for remote calls, which has a method "authenticate". That method, if successful, returns a "user" object. This user object can then be used by the client to get some data.

It looks like this:

```
RMIServer server = new RMIServer ();
Naming.rebind("rmi://"+ hostName +"/" + AUTH_OBJECT_BINDING, server);
```

RMIServer then has a method:

```
public InterfaceUser Authenticate(String username, String password);
```

This method checks the username/pw and returns a user object (actually the interface). The user object saves some string which contains the username, and a list of permissions. This can then be checked when calling other methods further down the line.

**My question is this:**

Someone wants to develop a (another) client for the server, to do this I would give them the interfaces required to interact with it (e.g, the InterfaceUser interface, as well as others). I would need to set up a fake "development" server somewhere to allow them to do this, which they can connect to. Is it possible for that developer to use the interfaces to allow it to get an instance of "InterfaceUser" from the real server without correctly authenticating? For example, Bob logs in to the real server, the server creates a User object which implements InteraceUser. Can Alice, with the interfaces, hijack that object or find it somehow on the registry? All other objects are exported on the same port (if this makes a difference).

Or, can Alice authenticate with the fake server, then somehow use that to access the real server? Let's assume that all usernames/passwords are different on the "real server" and the "development server"

Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Alice can't get any user object unless she can login to a server that provides it.
2. Any user object Alice does get is bound to the server that created it, and can't be used on another server. It doesn't even survive power cycling of the correct server.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think so yes, and that's also good news. This is what I originally thought when designing the system but had some doubt, as it was never intended that the interfaces would be given to a third party (and so this was not much of a consideration during my planning).